# Extending the training of the OpenNLP organisation model

Tags: nlp, opennlp, corpus

I am new to NLP and the OpenNLP libraries and am playing around at the moment with some of the functionality in particular the library's ability to extract names of organisations. If I use a simple string such as

```
"Bill worked at Microsoft Corp., JP Morgan Chase, Monsanto and General Motors and was amazed at what went on in Congress. "
```

my code drops out:

```
Detected name "Bill". Type person with probability of 0.9604452678787172
Detected name "Microsoft Corp .". Type organization with probability of 0.9976452599132802
Detected name "JP Morgan Chase". Type organization with probability of 0.9064399433766583
Detected name "Monsanto". Type organization with probability of 0.7429123227376515
Detected name "General Motors". Type organization with probability of 0.965472905375375
Detected name "Congress". Type organization with probability of 0.9940809804351413
```

The all seems fine. If, however, I switch to a more British view of the world such as

```
"Mark worked at The University of London, HSBC, The Royal Bank of Scotland, Dyson and GlaxoSmithKline."
```

I get

```
Detected name "Mark". Type person with probability of 0.7496973664676362
Detected name "London". Type location with probability of 0.6625435519843291
Detected name "Scotland". Type location with probability of 0.9564118675997605
Detected name "University of London". Type organization with probability of 0.8516268558212053
Detected name "Royal Bank". Type organization with probability of 0.8953174632171774
```

Clearly not as successful. Is this because of the fact that the organisation finder doesn't know about English institutions or have I just been unlucky? If the former is there a way for me to take the existing model and extend it's knowledge to cover the UK institutions better?. I had a quick look for the training data for the existing organisation model but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also couldn't find any documentation about the training data in a quick search, but it's probably trained on American newspaper text (Wall Street Journal or Reuters are likely from MUC or CoNLL datasets), which would explain why it doesn't do as well for British entities.

There's no way to extend an existing model, but you can train your own model with British entities if you have the annotated data.

Comment: Therein lies the problem. It's easy to obtain a list of all the British Companies Registered at companies house but could that be used to train the model? I'm to new at this to make a judgement

Comment: Not really, at least not with OpenNLP.  OpenNLP expects to have training data where the entities occur in context in sentences.  See the documentation: https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training

Comment: That is pretty much what I thought. Many thanks for your help